# Can't perform "sudo apt update" after installing ffmpeg

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, raspberrypi, ffmpeg

I run a raspberry pi 4. I have just installed ffmpeg for my discord music bot. For the bot to play music I installed ffmpeg, using "sudo apt install ffmpeg" and then "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-4". I used this video as installation guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tf4p-SMw5jA.

[After installation when I ran "sudo apt update":](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgec4.png)

When I got this error I didn't really care and moved on, later I wanted to update pi-hole.
[Then I got this error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwUsf.png)

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party sources; which means all checks are your responsibility. Did you check? as I see nothing useful in that PPA for your system...  https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg-4

Comment: I used "sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa" to delete it and now it works :D